# jquery button click is not firing in IE only

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a simple html input button, on click of which I do some logic and then trigger the click of and asp:Button which has a click event on server side. My code is working perfectly fine locally and on our test server but the click event doesn't fire on the client's server.

Moreover, the page works okay in Chrome and Mozilla everywhere!!!

so this problem is only on IE and only on one server

wait it gets even more weird..

If I debug the js code in IE, the event actually fires and page works fine.. remove the breakpoints and back to not working..

```
function someFunction()
{
if (arrRowCol.length > 0 || $('#hdnSaveNoteFlag').val() == "1") {
            getArrayValues();
            $('#imgLoading').offset({
                top: $(document).height() / 4,
                left: $(document).width() / 2
            });
            $('#tblWORView').hide();
            $('#imgLoading').show();
            $('#btnHiddenSave').click();
        }
        else {
            alert('There is no pending data.')
        }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try to replace `$('#btnHiddenSave').click();` with `$('#btnHiddenSave').trigger('click');`

Comment: Are you using `console.log` somewhere in your code?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/

Comment: @Oliboy50 any known reason for that?

Comment: Can you show us the rendered aspx?

Comment: @A.Wolff No reason, just an idea :)

Comment: @Oliboy50 ;) i more think Alvaro is right, OP is using console somewhere in code which makes IE thrown error in 'not debug mode'

Comment: replacing with $('#btnHiddenSave').trigger('click'); did not work :( and no I don't have console.log in my code

Comment: Now i wonder why my comment has gathered 2 upvotes... =s

Comment: do you need to see the rendered aspx?